# Django - pass commands to shell

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have an django project on Heroku and I need to update the DB daily. Manually i would open manage.py shell and write there this:

```
from app import views
views.function()
```

One way i found to do that automatic is through a heroku scheduler, however I would like to know if it is possible to tell the shell what commands should it run.

I was doing this:

```
python -c "from app import views;views.function"
```

but it gives me an error because that should be done on the shell instead of the command line, so is it possible to tell the shell what should it write?

Thanks :D

Comment: cron would also do a better job here

Comment: Cron is a good idea. Let me know if my answer helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom django command, something like my_command.py and call it from the command line:

```
python manage.py my_command
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for <3